# How to work with Code Commit repo cross IAM-user

Tags: git, aws-codecommit

I have an AWS account (DEV) xxxx. An EC2 instance runs on this account. Two repo on this account too (`Repo1`, `Repo2`)

I want to make an IAM user can access this repo via CLI cross credential of IAM user. That step I do:

- Attach role AWSCodeCommitPowerUser for Ec2 instance -> To make sure all user on instance can access Code Commit.
- Create group user have this policy:

  ```
  {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
      {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": [
              "codecommit:BatchGet*",
              "codecommit:Get*",
              "codecommit:List*",
              "codecommit:Create*",
              "codecommit:DeleteBranch",
              "codecommit:Describe*",
              "codecommit:Put*",
              "codecommit:Post*",
              "codecommit:Merge*",
              "codecommit:Test*",
              "codecommit:Update*",
              "codecommit:GitPull",
              "codecommit:GitPush"
          ],
          "Resource": ["arn:aws:codecommit:eu-west-1:xxxx:Repo1",
                      "arn:aws:codecommit:eu-west-1:xxxx:Repo2"
          ]
      },
  }
  ```
- Add IAM user into this group.
- Copy URL link of repo from AWS CodeCommit.
- Login EC2 instance, run command:

  ```
  git clone https://git-codecommit.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/Repo1
  ```
- It requires to enter username and password. I fill IAM user above, password of this user.

I got this error:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/Repo1/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Could anyone explain to me? I don't know what am I wrong.

In Ec2 instance, I installed it, setup email and user in `~/.gitconfig`. I don't run aws configure because I don't want to use access key and secretkey. It is not security.